# Use Ploty Dash-Extensions library on multi-app site

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

When i try to deploy a multi app site with Waitress/Plotly-Dash, Python stop working when we try to use the "Download" function of the Dash-Extensions library (https://pypi.org/project/dash-extensions/)

Is it possible to use it without crashing Python?

Site 1:

```py
    @app.callback(
    [Output("download-site1", "data"),Output("modal", "is_open")],
    [Input("btn-site1",'n_clicks'),Input("close-modal",'n_clicks')],
    [State("box-site1",'children'),State("modal", "is_open")],prevent_initial_call=True
    )
def crear_info(click,close_modal,box2,is_open):
    if dash.callback_context.triggered[0]['value'] is not None:
        if dash.callback_context.triggered[0]['prop_id'] =='btn-site1.n_clicks':
            print('Working')
            event= pd.read_json(json.loads(box2))

            import custom_lib as odl
            document,filename = odl.create_doc(event)
            def to_docx(path):
                document.save(path)
            
            return send_bytes(to_docx,filename),not is_open

            return dash.no_update,dash.no_update
        
        
        elif dash.callback_context.triggered[0]['prop_id'] =='close-modal.n_clicks':
            return dash.no_update,not is_open
    else:
        return dash.no_update,dash.no_update
```

```py
Site 2:

@app.callback(Output("download-site2", "data"),
              Input("csv", "n_clicks"),
              State('box-site2', 'children'),
              prevent_initial_call=True
              )
def download_csv(click,data):
    print('click!')
    import json
    import pandas as pd
    from dash_extensions.snippets import send_data_frame
    df = json.loads(data)
    df = pd.DataFrame(df)
    df = df.set_index('date_str',drop=True)
    return send_data_frame(df.to_excel, "spreadsheet.xls")
```

Comment: Please add a minimal example demonstrating the issue.

Comment: Now with minimal example :)